# file not found in xcode 4

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, openni

Hi i made a command line tool but when compiling i get this error :

[image]

which is rather strange because the file is in the right folder in the project :

[image]

I already tried removing it and then adding it again , but it didn't help.

Did i forget to include something etc ... ?
I'm not really familiar with xcode so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the GL folder.

```
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
```

Within OpenGL.framework is gl.h, glext.h, and whatnot, and it's adapted for mac.
If you insist on GL/gl.h, you need to add it to the project's header search path. To do this, go to your project's settings->build rules, and search "Include Paths". When you find the "Header Include Paths" section, type in "${SRCROOT}/". This assumes that GL/gl.h is in the same project as your folder.

Comment: Ok that fixed that thank you. Maybe you can solve this one too ? Same problem the file is there but xcode can't find the file '#include <glh/glh_obs.h>'

Comment: @Ojtwist Target Settings->Build Rules->Header Search Paths. Assuming that glh is in the same folder as your project is, type "${SRCROOT}" (with quotes), and that should fix it.

You could also include glh/glh_objs.h with "", instead of <>